# How to view website from different locations

Tags: cdn, cross-browser, proxy

I'm trying to view my website from different locations around the world.

I tried browser shot but it's not really accurate and does not allow me to select which country I want.

I specifically want to check from USA, Korea, China, Japan Australia, New Zealand etc.

Is there a good online website that allows this kind of services?

It seems like my cousin in Korea is getting website that is about 3 days old and cannot see any changes that I made since then. Could this be ISP propagation issue? I'm also using Cloudflare to speed up this process.

Answer (score 0):

When you access a web page from anywhere in the world, you access it directly from your server. ISPs do not cache pages or sites. It would not make sense that your cousin sees a 3-day old version EXCEPT he's probably seeing the cached version. He needs to clear his cache to get the current view.

To do that on Windows, just hit ctrl-R.